# Multivariable function derivative problem

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$. If $Df(x)x = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, show that $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I tried to prove $Df(x) = 0$ however I cannot find an approach, here the mean value inequality seems not applicable.

Comment: What it the notation $Df(x)x$? Is it the dot product? If so putting "\cdot" between might help, giving $Df(x)\cdot x$.

Comment: Df(x) is the derivative of f, is a linear transformation from R2→R

Comment: this is matrix multiplication but not dot production there..sorry about that

Comment: Also because dot product would result in PDE $xf_x+yf_y=0$ with solutions
$$
f(x,y)=u(y/x)
$$
with $u\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ arbitrary, which would not imply $f$ constant... Anyway, do you mean
$$
\begin{bmatrix} f_x \\ f_y\end{bmatrix}
[x, y] =
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \quad ??
$$

Comment: Df(x) should be a matrix of size 1x2 so Df(x) = (fx fy), the x should be an element belongs to R2, hence the Df(x)x should give us  a value belongs to R.

Comment: So
$$
[f_x, f_y]\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = xf_x+yf_y = Df(x,y)\cdot (x,y)
$$
I don't get what you mean by matrix multiplication rather than dot product.

Comment: From your edit it seems that you do mean dot product, so that $f(x,y)=u(y/x)$ with $u\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ arbitrary. Therefore $f$ need not be constant.

Comment: ok.. actually it does not matter it is either a dot product or matrix multiplication( because I treat (x,y) as a column vector.. yeah.. thank for your counterexample.. I think this question is wrong with itself..

Comment: Oh.. but @AndreasT, note the question requires f is continuous on R2, however f(x,y)=(y/x) is not..

Comment: @user59118 Yeah, you are right, I'm working on an answer to that issue. I am still not sure that $f$ need be constant though

Comment: @user59118 At last it seems that $f$ has to be constant :)

Answer (score 1):

$Df(x,y)\cdot (x,y)=0$ gives the PDE $xf_x+yf_y=0$ that has solutions
$$
f(x,y)=u(y/x) \quad\text{with $u\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ arbitrary}
$$
In order to be continuous, since $u\in C^1(\mathbb R)$, it remains to discuss the behavior of $f$ as $x\to 0$. In particular, there must exist a constant $\ell$ such that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}u(y/x)=\ell
$$
Studying the linear trajectories $y=mx$ with $m\in\mathbb R$, yields to
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}u(m)=\ell \quad\forall m\in\mathbb R
$$
so that $u$ has to be constant, $u\equiv\ell$. It follows that $f$ is constant too: $f(x,y)\equiv\ell$.

Conversely, it is trivial that if $f$ is constant then it satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: thanks, nice solution, it also gives me ideas how to solve this without using PDE